# Mocking a service in Spring 5.0.7.RELEASE

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, junit, mockito

I have a Spring 5.0.7.RELEASE app, with some WebLayer tests I have this test in my app:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
public class HongoControllerTest  {

    @Mock
    FactureService factureService;

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext wac;

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    ObjectMapper obj = new ObjectMapper();


    @Before
    public void setup() {

        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(this.wac)
                .build();

        when(factureService.setLockFilter(any())).thenReturn(Boolean.TRUE);
    }
}
```

but when I run the test, the FactureService is not mocked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not totally sure because you didn't show an actual test but I guess you should use `@MockBean` and not `@Mock`.

`@Mock` is used for plain Unit Test when you do the dependency injection yourself.
`@MockBean` is used for integration tests when you want to use your Mock as a regular Bean.

Long story shot. Try this:

```
@MockBean
FactureService factureService;
```

For more information have a look on this [article](https://rieckpil.de/difference-between-mock-and-mockbean-spring-boot-applications/).

Comment: But @MockBean belongs to SpringBoot, not Spring and I am using Spring not SpringBoot :-(